# Pass ValueConverter to CustomControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, ivalueconverter

I'm stuck on a problem and I'm sure this happened because I'm not using WPF as I should. I will try to describe my situation and would appreciate any ideas.

I'm about to create a `CustomControl` that shows a numerical value and can show validation errors for this value. The control is part of a control library and does not know anything about the value or its validation but should show validation errors as a tooltip. Therefore I used the default style to add a trigger:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

What I want to do now is to give the user of the control the possibility to translate the validation error with the help of a converter. Therefore I added a `DependencyProperty`to the custom control:

```
public IValueConverter LocConverter
{
    get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(LocConverterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LocConverterProperty, value); }
}
```

I was trying to use this converter via a binding:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent,
                        Converter={Binding LocConverter,
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyControl}}}}" />
```

But this is causing a runtime error because I cannot use a binding for a converter.

Is there another possibility to bind a converter or an idea how to pass a translation method to the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the best way to apply a binding that depends on two or more values which may change independently (in this case, your error content and your converter) is to use a `MultiBinding`.  You could write a custom `IMultiValueConverter` that accepts the error content as its first value and the converter as its second value, then use the provided converter to perform the actual conversion.  The `MultiBinding` will be reevaluated when either the error content or your `LocConverter` changes.